# Track user activity from different domains (but same site) with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, usage-statistics, visitor-statistic

I've got a site that has many domains and subdomains. They all go to the same pages and do the same stuff. The only thing that changes from domain to domain is the images and colors of the site. So I wanna track the users activity and started using google analytics. I changed the google script to this:

```
<script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
      ga('require', 'linker');
      ga('linker:autoLink', ['domain2.com'] );
      ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

But this only gives me the data from all activities in the browser no matter from which domain it came. I wanna know if it's possible to also separate which domain had more hits and stuff like that. Is it possible? Is there any other tool where this is possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: To clarify, you have multiple domains (example.com, example2.com) and want to track traffic individually on each domain as separate traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are tracking all (and any) of your domains with that code snippet you provided. Some best practices are to

1. set up a view for each domain (with the appropriate `Include` filter applied) and also
2. set up a Roll-up view that contains data for all your domains, and you would definitely need an `Prepend hostname` filter so you can see which domain traffic comes in from.
3. set up a Raw view that is completely unfiltered,
4. and finally set up a Test view for testing out new configurations.

Edit: Here's a screenshot of how you would include a filter for a specific domain:

[image]

Comment: But those configurations are done in that script or in the google analytics site?

Comment: No, not in terms of the reporting aspects. The code snippet establishes the tracker wherever it is placed, collects data for those specific pages on which it is placed, and configures cross-domain tracking, but in terms of what you actually see in the reports, you would need to create filters for that purpose.

Comment: I tried to include a filter for one of the domains but isn't working. Can you show me an example?

Comment: I've created the view with the domain filter and says it doesn't have any traffic. Does it take some time to appear the information?

Comment: Yes, you would need to wait at least 24 hours for data to appear in your new view, but you could also check in real-time reports possibly.